# Modular Elliptic Curves and Eta Products

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

The elliptic curve $E:y^2+y=x^3-x^2$ of conductor $11$ is interesting as the associated modular form (this is over $\bf Q$) is 
$$
F=q\prod_{n>0}(1-q^n)^2(1-q^{11n})^2
$$
Clearly this exhibits a very nice $\eta$-product.

Is anyone aware of other elliptic curves over $\bf Q$ which have a simple minimal equation and whose associated modular form is a nice $\eta$-product or even a nice $\eta$-quotient?

Comment: Every weight $2$ eta product which is a modular form is the L-function of an elliptic curve. Such a formula in term of $\eta$ is useful for the BSD conjecture. Not sure if that it doesn't vanish on the upper half-plane is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are a few elliptic curves whos modular forms exhibit such nice factorizations in terms of the $eta$-function. One example that I (re)found a while ago is

$$E/\mathbb{Q}:\,y^2=x^3+1$$

which has the associated modular form

$$\eta^4(6\tau).$$

You can view more of these [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/246102693_Eta-quotients_and_elliptic_curves). And while trying to find that PDF again, I also found this had been asked previously on [math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33058/eta-products-and-modular-elliptic-curves).

Comment: Ah thank you for the link, it is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you mean the MO-link or the first link with the paper by Ono?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually both, the MO question is weirdly similar to mine, even the conductor is the same.

Answer (score 2):

For several values of $\lambda\in \Bbb Q\setminus \{0,1\}$ the elliptic curves

$$E_{\lambda}\colon y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$$
correspond to modular forms which are linear combinations of eta-quotients, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.0337). For more details see the [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33058/eta-products-and-modular-elliptic-curves), also linked by $dx dy dz$.